# How to modify the text arrangement in legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I want to customize the number of rows in each column of the matplotlib legend text.

The code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

for i in range(10):
    plt.plot(np.linspace(0, 5, 5), np.random.randint(0, 10, 5), label=str(i))

plt.legend(ncol = 3, loc = 1)
plt.show()
```

What I get: the numbers of rows in each column are 4, 3, 3
[image]

What I want: the numbers of rows in each column are 4, 4, 2

[image]

I've tried adding `plt.plot([], [], label='')` before `plt.show()`, but it doesn't help

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by adding an invisible line as 11th element like this:

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

lines = []
for i in range(10):
    l, = plt.plot(np.linspace(0, 5, 5), np.random.randint(0, 10, 5), label=str(i))
    lines.append(l)

l, = plt.plot(0, alpha=0, label=' ')   
# alpha=0 will make the line and element in the legend invisible
lines.append(l)

plt.legend(handles=[l for l in lines], ncol = 3, loc = 1)
plt.show()
```

This will yield the following result:
[image]